# Как вставить пробел после каждых двух символов в строке?

Tags: c++, строки

Начиная с конца с помощью std::string ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну что-то решение приведено из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно?"..

Только поэтому дам и свой ответ на уже закрытый вопрос...

```
string space2(const string& s)
{
    if (s.length() <= 2) return s;
    int n = 2-s.length()%2;
    string r(s,0,n);
    for(auto it = s.begin()+n; it != s.end();)
    {
        r += ' '; r += *it++; r += *it++;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Для скорости можно добавить

```
r.reserve(s.length()*3/2);
```

Поскольку принятый ответ тоже возвращает другую (отличную от исходной) строку, не стал добавлять решение для требования работать в рамках строго одной строки - но оно в принципе такое же.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, например, так:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
  std::string str = "Hello World!!";
  int counter = -1;
  std::string str2;
  std::for_each(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), [&counter, &str2](char s)
                    {
                      counter++;
                      if(counter == 2)
                        {
                          counter = 0;
                          str2 += " ";
                        }
                      str2+= s;});
  std::string str3;
  std::for_each(str2.rbegin(), str2.rend(), [&str3](char s) {
                            str3 += s;});
  std::cout << str3 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

rbegin() и rend() разворачивают строку.

Comment: `std::reverse(str2.begin(), str2.end());` вместо второго `for_each`